# PHP exclude conflict

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have a problem:
I have an array of words to exclude
(example: Yellow and yellow table)
I replace with str_replace the word by the same word with tags around for exclusion, but I have a problem:

I think the problem comes from the order of the words in the table to exclude when there are words that come into conflict, but I cannot sort them manually in advance, because I do not know them (this is is the user who fills them in)

How could I do it?

Here is my code:

```php
$text = "I want to exclude the Yellow table in php";

$excluded_words_wrappers = array('<span>', '</span>');
$excluded_words = array('table', 'Yellow table');

foreach ($excluded_words as $excluded_word) {
    $excluded_word = trim($excluded_word);
    $match = "{$excluded_words_wrappers[0]}{$excluded_word}{$excluded_words_wrappers[1]}";
    $text = str_replace($excluded_word, $match, $text);
}

echo $text;

/**
 - Example sentence: I want to exclude the Yellow table in php  
 - What i get with my code: I want to exclude the <span>yellow</span> table in
   php
 - What I want: I want to exclude the <span>Yellow table</span> in
   php
**/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your list of excluded words by their lengths (`strlen($excluded_word)`), such that longer words appear first (index 0) and shorter words appear last.

Therefore, 'yellow table' appears before 'yellow'. You don't care that 'blue' is out of place, only that it appears after anything that would conflict with it. For example:

- table
- yellow
- yellow table
- blue
- blue table

would sort as:

- yellow table
- blue table
- yellow
- table
- blue

Your problem appears when one excluded word contains another excluded word. Any excluded word that contains another excluded word, must, by its very nature, be longer than the contained excluded word. If you were to process 'yellow' before 'yellow table' and change 'yellow' to 'red', for example (or wrap it with `<span></span>`) then all occurrences of 'yellow table' will be changed to 'red table'. But if you process the longer excluded words first, then you will process 'yellow table' before 'yellow', and you will get the results you're looking for.

Issue a sort command just before your `foreach` statement. You could use usort() with a user-defined comparison function.
[usort syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Thank you, indeed I had not thought of it.  on the other hand, by making his the longest word will be surrounded by span, but the shorter will be it too, is there a way to avoid this?  avoid "exclusion within exclusion". Avoir this: ``` <span>Yellow <span>table</span></span>```

Comment: Use preg_replace() instead of str_replace() such that the excluded word must not be preceded by > nor followed by <

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
<?php
// first arg is text to replace on, all remaining arguments are words you wrap in a span *(except last true or 1 - that makes it case sesitive)*
function spanWords(...$args){
  $str = array_shift($args); $end = end($args);
  if($end === true || $end === 1){
    array_pop($args); $i = '/';
  }
  else{
    $i = '/i';
  }
  return preg_replace('/'.join('|', $args).$i, '<span>$0</span>', $str);
}
echo spanWords('I want to exclude the Yellow table in php', 'yellow table');
?>
```